# Favourite tagged questions: highlight colors, too bright?..

Tags: support, design, user-interface

I can't distinguish favourite questions, which are highlighted, on the front page from others, even if I squint. The only way to notify them is to change my viewing angle to something other than 90°.

I have Samsung SyncMaster 940N LCD which is probably not best at color rendering, even fine tuning doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think the highlight is too subtle. The main problem is that LCD color rendering is inconsistent enough that some shades simply disappear. I have two panels on the machine I'm typing from and the cheap LG one shows just a hint of shading but I have to look carefully. The much more expensive high end ViewSonic monitor shows absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot of the favorite question highlight color:

[image: favorite questions highlight]

Not sure how others feel about this, but it is visible on my typical TN (aka crappy) panels I have.

Comment: It's visible to me, but it's also reasonably easy to miss.

Comment: Hardly visible here (at home it's slightly better).